# how to avoid truncation of numbers- Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file, which I split into parts with 10 lines each using Python. I am trying to split them with 4 digit suffixes instead of 1,2,3,etc. For example, if the file is filename.txt, then the file must be split into, filepart-0000.txt, filepart-0001.txt and so on. Right now, if I have:

suffix = 0000

And then try to write to the filepart as:
open ("filepart-" + str(suffix),'w')

I still end up getting: 
filepart-0.txt, filepart-1.txt and so on.

If I straightaway write:
open ("filepart-" + suffix, 'w')

I (obviously) end up with 'TypeError:cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects'
Is there a way I can retain the entire suffix of four digits? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) with a `0` padding as follows:

```
In [1]: '{:04}'.format(1)
Out[1]: '0001'

In [2]: '{:04}'.format(23)
Out[2]: '0023'
```

The idea is that you can then provide your target integers as you usually would, but pass them in as the argument to `format` in order to pad the digit with 0s so that it contains at least 4 digits. You can then use that string in your filename.

```
In [3]: for i in xrange(1, 11):
   ...:     print 'filename-{:04}.txt'.format(i)
   ...:     
filename-0001.txt
filename-0002.txt
filename-0003.txt
filename-0004.txt
filename-0005.txt
filename-0006.txt
filename-0007.txt
filename-0008.txt
filename-0009.txt
filename-0010.txt
```